# Error en PHP sqlsrv_num_rows()

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Hice un programa de multiquery pero con mysqli para hacer pruebas ya que no me dejan llevar información del trabajo, donde se trabaja con sql server y al pasar la conexión y demás sentencias en el php a sql server me sale este error:

> sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Ult\process.php on line 40

les dejo el código

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
function creaWhere($attr, $cols){
    $tmp = ""; // variable temporal para sacar los wheres de la query
    if (count($attr) != 0) {
        foreach ($attr as $val) {
            $tmp .= " (";
            foreach ($cols as $col) {
                $tmp .= ($col === end($cols))? $col." LIKE "."'%".$val."%'" : $col." LIKE "."'%".$val."%' OR ";
            }
            $tmp .= ($val === end($attr))? ")" : ") AND";
        }
        return $tmp;
    }else{ return "1";} //regresa 1 para mostrar todos los datos de la tabla
}
include "dicc.php";
//variables POST
$serch = utf8_encode($_POST['search']);
$table = $_POST['table'];
//--------------
$attr = explode(' ', $serch); //agregamos cada palabra del search a una entrada de attr
//coneccion a BD cambiar por sql
/*$conn = new sqlsrv_connect (SVR, USR, PSS, DBO);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}*/
$serverName = "10.21.22.16"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"RENAPO", "UID"=>"registrocivil", "PWD"=>"rc21", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
//-------------------------------
$where = creaWhere($attr, $COLUMNS[$DBOS[$table]]); //le metemos los atributos de busqueda y las columnas en las que debe de buscar a la funcion
$query = "SELECT ". implode(", ", $SELECTS[$DBOS[$table]]) ." FROM RENAPO.".$DBOS[$table]." WHERE ". $where; //crea la query que devolvera las columnas indicadas en el diccionario en el array SELECTS
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered")); //ejecuta la query
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($results) == 0) { //checa si hay resultados
    $hay = 0;
}else {
    $hay = 1; 
    $headers = array_keys($results->fetch_assoc()); // si hay resultados extrae los headers de las columnas para despues ponerlo en la tabla html
}
 ?>
```

Y aquí pongo el dicc.php

```
<?php 
define("SVR", "10.21.22.16"); //direccion del servidor
define("USR", "registrocivil"); //usuario con permisos sobre la base
define("PSS", "rc21"); //pass en este caso el usuario entra sin pass
define("DBO", "RENAPO"); //base de datos donde esta todo el desma
$DBOS = ["NACIMEXT", "DEFUNEXT", "MATREXT"]; // array con las tablas a las que se accesan (esta coordinado con los values del combobox)
//columnas en las que se buscaran los datos
$COLUMNS = [
    "NACIMEXT" => ["NOMBRE", "PATERNO", "MATERNO", "FECHANAC", "ACTA", "LIBRO", "ANO", "MUNICIPIO", "JUZGADO"],
    "DEFUNEXT" => ["NOMBREFIN", "MATERNOFIN", "FECHADEF", "MUNICIPIO", "ANO", "LIBRO", "JUZGADO", "ACTA"],
    "MATREXT" => ["NOMBREEL", "PATERNOEL", "MATERNOEL", "NOMBREELLA", "PATERNOELLA", "MATERNOELLA", "FECHAREGIS", "MUNICIPIO", "ANO", "JUZGADO", "LIBRO", "ACTA"]
];
//instrucciones de como desplegar los datos
$SELECTS = [
    "NACIMEXT" => [ "NOMBRE as Nombres", 
                    "PATERNO as 'Apellido Paterno'", 
                    "MATERNO as 'Apellido Materno'", 
                    "FECHANAC as 'Fecha de Nacimiento'", 
                    "ACTA as 'Número de Acta'", 
                    "LIBRO as 'Número de Libro'", 
                    "ANO as Año", "MUNICIPIO as Municipio", 
                    "JUZGADO as 'Número de Juzgado'"],

    "DEFUNEXT" => [ "NOMBREFIN as Nombres", "MATERNOFIN as 'Apellido Materno'", 
                    "FECHADEF as 'Fecha de Defunción'", "MUNICIPIO as Municipio", 
                    "LIBRO as 'Número de Libro'", 
                    "ANO as Año", 
                    "JUZGADO as 'Número de Juzgado'", 
                    "ACTA as Acta"],

    "MATREXT" => [  "CONCAT(NOMBREEL, ' ', PATERNOEL, ' ', MATERNOEL, ' y ', NOMBREELLA, ' ', PATERNOELLA, ' ', MATERNOELLA) as Casados", 
                    "MUNICIPIO as Municipio", 
                    "LIBRO as 'Número de Libro'", 
                    "ANO as Año", 
                    "JUZGADO as 'Número de Juzgado'", 
                    "ACTA as Acta"]
]
 ?>
```

Comment: Parece que estás realizando los pasos correctos, creando el recurso antes de usarlo en la función de query y pasándoselo en el argumento correcto. No obstante y solo para descartar cualquier otro problema, podrías hacer un `var_dump` del recurso `$conn` antes del chequeo `$conn === false`. ¿Qué te arroja entonces?

Comment: Me aparece lo siguiente `resource(3, SQL Server Connection)`

Comment: Parece correcta la respuesta de Ricardo, básicamente es verificar que la consulta también fue correcta, y manejarla en caso de que no, al igual que manejas ya el caso en que no se puede crear la conexión correctamente.

Comment: Si Ricardo me dio la respuesta a ese error, pero al resolverlo ahora me arroja uno nuevo `Call to a member function sqlsrv_fetch_array() on a non-object in` y es en esta linea `$headers = array_keys($results->fetch_assoc());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según el manual, sobre el resultado de la función sqlsrv_query:

> Returns a statement resource on success and FALSE if an error
>   occurred.

O sea, que devuelve un recurso válido o **false**. En tu código no compruebas si la consulta tuvo éxito (mala costumbre) y automáticamente llamas a sqlsrv_num_rows() pasándole como argumento en vez de un recurso válido, un false, pues muy probablemente la consulta no tuvo éxito o tuvo algún error.

Primero deberías comprobar si la consulta tuvo éxito:

```
$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
if($results === false)
{
echo "Error en la consulta: $query";
}
else
{
   // tu código
   if (sqlsrv_num_rows($results) == 0) { //checa si hay resultados
     $hay = 0;
   } 
   else
   {
    $hay = 1; 
    $headers = array_keys($results->fetch_assoc()); 
   }
}
```

Y luego qué es lo que falló, la sintaxis de la consulta o algún otro factor.

Comment: Genial, tenías razón era eso, tenía un error en la consulta, desde ahora haré esa comprobación, pero ahora salió un nuevo error el cual es 
Call to a member function sqlsrv_fetch_array() on a non-object in
En la linea 51 la cual es:
`$headers = array_keys($results->fetch_assoc());`

Comment: Es que estás tratando un recurso como si fuera un objeto. Imagino que lo que querías hacer era ésto en la línea 51: `$headers = array_keys(sqlsrv_fetch_array($results,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: Genial, olvidé eso, gracias enserio ya imprime, pero con un warning sobre el UTF-8 `Warning: utf8_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in` que esta en estas lineas `if($hay){
     while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($results)) {
      echo "<tr>";
       foreach ($result as $col) {
        echo "<td>". utf8_decode($col) ."</td>";
       }
      echo "</tr>";` lo cual no entiendo si esta declarado en el connectioInfo

Comment: ¿Donde estás llamando a utf8_decode?